# How to use jqgrid inlinenav edit and save functionality

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav

Need help in understanding the approach for Jqgrid inlineNav Edit and Save functionality..
I could not find any previous topic which explains how we do the Edit & save using Jqgird inLineNav + .net MVC.. If we have any can you point me in right direction..

I am new to Jquery and Jqgrid.. Currently working in .net MVC Project where I need to implement inlineNav Edit.

Can someone explain me the following thing.

1. Onclicking the Edit button how do I store all row data in editParams for save function?
2. Onclicking InlineNav save how do I pass the Data to my controller Action?
3. Can you provide me any simple example for JQgrid InlineNav Edit & save function.

Thanks in advance..

Update:

I found a easy instruction in this site.

http://tpeczek.com/2009/11/jqgrid-and-aspnet-mvc-crud.html

But here for save, the example uses FormCollection as input param for controller Action.

```
public ActionResult EditProduct(FormCollection postData)
{
//Editing product based on postData
  Product product = _repository.GetProduct(Convert.ToInt32(postData["id"]));
return json("success");
}
```

But I need to use my model instead of form collection. If I use my model its not working.. 
the call is not posted to my controller action. Pls help??

Thanks..